# dropbox, whats the difference between drop-in and datastores

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I am going to build a simple gallery web site.  It will go to dropbox to get all image files.

before i gets started, i need to choose between drop-in and datastores.  for Datastores,Your app can only access data through the Datastore API. but what is drop-ins?  I have a hard time to understand what this is.  I also want to know why I should choose one over another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop-ins are lightweight UI components that let you easily open a file from Dropbox or save a file to Dropbox.

Datastores are basically NoSQL databases that live in a user's Dropbox. They don't deal with files at all; they let you store tables with records and fields.

In your case, you probably don't want either. You want the [Core API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core), which gives you full access to read and write user's files in Dropbox.